# How to protect access to /metrics and /health in Helidon MP?

Tags: helidon

[/metrics](https://helidon.io/docs/v2/#/mp/guides/05_metrics) and [/health](https://helidon.io/docs/v2/#/mp/guides/04_health) are usefull endpoints in Helidon MP but can disclose too much information publicly

Is there a way to protect access to those endpoints ?
With login/password or IP whitefiler ?

I didn't find anything on this in [/metrics](https://helidon.io/docs/v2/#/mp/guides/05_metrics) and [/health](https://helidon.io/docs/v2/#/mp/guides/04_health) documentation, stackoverflow.

Comment: I think you should check CORS https://helidon.io/docs/v3/#/mp/cors/cors . It is about restricting access to hose endpoints as well.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov CORS is just some browser foo and not a solution for this case. A simple curl command would access their endpoints. The OP needs access control restrictions on protected resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [security section in Helidon docs](https://helidon.io/docs/v3/#/mp/security/security) describes how you can protect your endpoints through one of the various auth integrations. Authorization is a vast topic, choose your poison wisely!